# Want to Code Cases on alert on bodyload

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have Remind_Date option in my table and I want to compare Remind_Date with Current_Date. If both are equal then alert will pop up on body on load showing corresponding member name. and also I want to develop cases for the alert. Alert will pop up 2 days or 3 days before remind date.

```
$now=date("Y/m/d"); 
            $sql = "select RemindDate from payment "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $RemindDate=$rowval2['RemindDate']; 
        } 


    $sql = "select MemName from payment where $RemindDate = '".$now."' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($rowval2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $MemName=$rowval2['MemName']; 
        } 
            ?>


</script> 
<body onload= "alert('<?php echo $MemName ; ?>')">
```

Comment: And what is your exact question?

Comment: I not getting alert on body load.. as alert is not taking php code .. for example:- <body onload= "alert('<?php global $MemName; print $MemName; ?>')">

Comment: Open generated html, see what you have. Open developers console check errors. Do a debug!

Comment: do suggest some other methods.alert is blank.

Comment: @priya Put your code in the question, not a comment. Show how you're setting `$MemName`. You don't need to use `global` unless this code is inside a PHP function.

Comment: when i delete global $memName.....error is generated of undefined memname.

Comment: Because if the column is empty it will act as undefined and show error. In this condition you have to write if else part in function and call that function in body onload event, Not directly alert().

Comment: What is the value of $MemName before the closing PHP tag? Can you `var_dump($MemName)` after the while and show us the result?